# Selenium: Store text into variable for future validation

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, selenium, validation

Using Selenium in Visual Studio.

I need help writing two testcases.
UPDATED:

1. Copy a serial-number from a text field and store this data in a variable.
2. Copy a serial-number from another text-field and store that data in another variable. And then compare Variable A with Variable B to verify that both are the same.

I want these testcases to be dynamic so I don't have to specify the actual serial-number. Instead I want to copy the contents of `<h3>` not matter what serial-number they contain.

The HTML where I want to copy the serial-number looks like this:

```
<lina-list-item _ngcontent-c34="" _nghost-c40="">
 <p _ngcontent-c34="">Serienummer</p>
 <h3 _ngcontent-c34="">Calpower11<!----></h3>
</lina-list-item>
```

I want to copy the *data* from `<h3>` into Variable A.

This is the complete Xpath for this specific `<h3>`:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/mat-dialog-container/lina-device-details-dialog/div/mat-tab-group/div/mat-tab-body[1]/div/div/div[2]/lina-device-information/div[1]/div[1]/lina-list-wrapper/div/lina-list-item[1]/h3
```

Then I want to copy the *data* from another `<h3>` into variable B

This is the complete Xpath for this specific `<h3>`:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/mat-dialog-container/lina-register-case-dialog/form/div/div/div[1]/div/lina-device-information-compact/div/div[2]/div[1]/lina-list-wrapper/div/lina-list-item[1]/h3
```

The HTML for the second `<h3>`:

```
<lina-list-item _ngcontent-c49="" _nghost-c40="">
 <p _ngcontent-c49="">Serienummer</p>
 <h3 _ngcontent-c49="">Calpower11</h3>
</lina-list-item>
```

As you can see the HTML doesn't differ much. Only by looking at the complete Xpath can you notice the difference.

Note: All testcases are called `"public void TestCaseName()"` so I hope this will make the variable I create accessible in all other testcases?

Summary:

1. Help me copy text from one `<h3>` into variable A
2. Help me copy text from another `<h3>` into variable B
3. Help me compare variable A and B to make sure they contain the same data.

Comment: Identifying an element through it's text and then later using `.Text` to extract the same text isn't the ideal approach. Can you update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML so both the elements can be identified uniquely?

Comment: @DebanjanB I've updated the question. I've specified the complete Xpath to the two different `<h3>` so it's easier to identify them. Please tell me if you need more info.

Comment: Using absolute _Xpath_ is a good way to start with but in the long run you may like to prefer relative _Xpath_. Hence the text based actual HTML is necessary to answer your question canonically.

Comment: @DebanjanB If I try to copy the entire HTML document and paste it here its too big and it looses its "tree structure". 

Using Selenium IDE I am able to identify the relative Xpath. Is that enough for you to help me. Or do you need the entire HTML?

Comment: It's fine if the text based HTML looses the tree structure, most important is we need the HTML including the parent node which will help us to identify both the nodes uniquely.

Comment: @DebanjanB Added the HTML in a google doc. See Updated Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the text value or attribute value like that.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//lina-list-item[1]/h3[contains(text(),'Calpower11')]"));
String serialNumber = element.Text;
```

OR

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//lina-list-item[1]/h3[contains(text(),'Calpower11')]"));
String serialNumber = element.GetAttribute("innerHtml");
```

---

Then compare the serial number like that.

```
if (serialNumber.Equals("Calpower11", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{ 
    //statement
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my first post was a little unclear. I don't want to write the specific serial-number (Calpower11) anywhere. I want the testcases to be dynamic. Please read my updated question.

Comment: @David : You need to share either url or more html to check two elements are present on the webpage.

Comment: I've added the HTML in a google doc link. See Updated Question.